# How to add datapoints in loop Oxyplot

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, oxyplot

Is it possible to add datapoints in loop?

```
public partial class Chart: Window
    {
        public IList<DataPoint> W1 { get; set; }

        public Chart(Learn l1)
        {
            int z = Convert.ToInt32(l1.counter);  
            {
                this.W1 = new List<DataPoint>
                            {
```

I want to add there for() loop to go thought l1.ww1 points and include it inside W1 oxyplot list

```
                new DataPoint(l1.ww1[i],i),
            };
 }


 InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try that code you have there?

Comment: Ive got solution `this.W1 = new List<DataPoint>();
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                W1.Add(new DataPoint(l1.ww1[i], i));
            } `